# How to upload a json file in mongodb using Java?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am trying to upload a big JSON file(newclicklogs.json) into mongodb using Java. Here is how my JSON file looks like:

```
{"preview":false,"result":{"search_term":"rania","request_time":"Sat Apr 01 12:47:04 -0400 2017","request_ip":"127.0.0.1","stats_type":"stats","upi":"355658761","unit":"DR","job_title":"Communications Officer","vpu":"INP","organization":"73","city":"Wash","country":"DC","title":"Tom","url":"www.demo.com","tab_name":"People-Tab","page_name":"PEOPLE","result_number":"5","page_num":"0","session_id":"df234f468cb3fe8be","total_results":"5","filter":"qterm=rina","_time":"2017-04-01T12:47:04.000-0400"}}
{"preview"......}
{"preview"......}
....
```

Here is my Java code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.bson.Document;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String jsonString = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("data/newclicklogs.json"), "UTF-8");

        Document doc = Document.parse(jsonString);
        List<Document> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(doc);

        new MongoClient().getDatabase("test2").getCollection("collection1").insertMany(list);

    }
}
```

When I query my mongodb collection, only one document is getting added. How can I add all the documents from my file into a mongodb collection. I am a newbie to mongodb. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try using the bulk writes with buffered reader.

The below code will read the json data from file, one line (document) at time, parse the json to `Document` and batch requests before writing it to database.

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("test2");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("collection1");

int count = 0;
int batch = 100;

List<InsertOneModel<Document>> docs = new ArrayList<>();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/newclicklogs.json"))) {
      String line;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         docs.add(new InsertOneModel<>(Document.parse(line)));
         count++;
         if (count == batch) {
           collection.bulkWrite(docs, new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false));
           docs.clear();
           count = 0;
        }
    }
}

if (count > 0) {
   collection.bulkWrite(docs, new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false));
}
```

When you run `Document.parse` on the entire json you are essentially reducing the documents to last document by overwriting all of previous ones.

More here

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/bulk-writes/

Comment: Thanks a lot, Veeram. I've been trying to figure this out from hours. You saved my day

Comment: May I know why you specified batch equal to 100?

Comment: You are welcome. Tbh I didn't even think about it. You can try running at different batch sizes and time them and pick the right one for your need. I believe for 60K records it shouldn't really make a big difference from one batch size to another.

Comment: Ok. Cool. I will research on that :)

Comment: Use (count % batch == 0) if you want to keep the count throughout the entire process.